# oauth2 cannot fetch token: bad request

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, request, google-oauth, token

I write a handler so that when accessing the route `/auth/google/callback`, I try to login with Google account through OAuth2. The handler is implemented like this:

```
package route

import (
    "net/http"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "fmt"
)

func GoogleOAuthHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conf:=&oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:"myclientid",
        ClientSecret:"myclientsecret",
        RedirectURL:"http://localhost:3000",
        Scopes:[]string{
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        },
        Endpoint:google.Endpoint,
    }

    code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")

    token, err := conf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(token)

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusMovedPermanently)
}
```

In `func main()`, `http.HandleFunc("/auth/google/callback",route.GoogleOAuthHandler)` is setup

When I access that path, it throws an error like this on browser:

```
oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Missing required parameter: code"
}
```

Did I miss something? Please instruct me to make a proper access to OAuth2 and get token and information from Google account

Comment: Did you defined the `code` url parameter? I cannot find it.

Comment: @SimoEndre How can I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access an url parameter (`code`) which is not defined in your url.

`r.URL.Query().Get()` returns an url parameter defined in the url address. In your case you are searching for `code` param, which is missing.

Checking the [`Exchange`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Exchange) method, this converts an authorization code into a token.

```
func (c *Config) Exchange(ctx context.Context, code string) (*Token, error).
```

The token in your case is an url parameter, but it's not declared. To sum up please include the token string in the url as a parameter otherwise declare somewhere in your code.

Comment: I've been learning how to use Google OAuth2. I haven't got it: How can I include or declared it specifically?

Comment: The error is not related to Google OAuth2. It's related how you are trying to parse a url parameter. The error says that you are trying to access the  `code` parameter form the url, but this one is not existing.  Check this ones: https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query, https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Get